# Android MediaPlayer.snoop(): How do you get future audio data?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, visualizer, snoop

This is something that I'm guessing is impossible without weird work arounds if its possible at all.  However,

***How would I use snoop() (or something like it) to get audio data for the audio approximately 10 seconds in advance or for the entire audio file(s) playing in the background?***

I have little to no idea how this would work.  However, one idea was maybe record 10 seconds of audio + audio data (somehow) and delay the playback or just not allow it to play for those ten seconds and then play it 10 seconds later with the audio stuff already recorded.  This sounds pretty impossible because I feel like you wouldn't be able to halt or otherwise silence audio playing from a device.

I want to use this for a game in which the player reacts to the songs that they are playing inn their media player.  That's why it would be useful to show the user what the audio data looks like before it actually comes up in the song.

Anyway, help would be greatly appreciated and it would improve the game a ton!

Thanks in advance,
Karl

Comment: Hmm, it seems like a difficult task, but from my understand you already have a method for snooping audio in real time. I would suggest asking a question that requests downloading a mediafile

Comment: It should be easier if you play the songs from your app directly as its own media player.  That way you'll have access to the audio stream directly.

Comment: It would be easier to  do that but I feel like one of the strengths of the app is its ability to adapt to the songs that you are playing.  In other words, not having to quit your favorite media player just to run the app.  But that has been something I have been considering.

Answer (score 0):

The implementations it is very device dependent!

Theoretically will work on all devices and Os, but far away is not true!

I have used the play() in 7 device test on the 8th doesn't worked!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you mean the MediaPlayer.snoop() or MediaPlayer.play()?

Comment: it isn't clear from my answer which sentence to which method belongs too?